# Borrowing and temporary variables in hashmap is throwing circular errors

Tags: rust, borrowing

I am having trouble getting a piece of code to work, as the errors I am getting are circular.

I start with the following code:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

let mut hashm = HashMap::<Vec<&str>, &str>::new();
for i in v {
    let s = i.split('\t').collect::<Vec<&str>>();
    let j = s[0]
        .replace(&['{', '}'][..], "") // replace multiple at once; https://users.rust-lang.org/t/24554/2
        .split(", ")
        .collect::<Vec<&str>>();
    let k = s[1];
    hashm.insert(j, k);
}
```

The error I get says that `s[0]`

```rust
creates a temporary which is freed while still in use... 
hashm.insert(j, k);
             - borrow later used here
```

So I change `hashm.insert(j, k)` to `hashm.insert(&j, k)` and `HashMap::<Vec<&str>, &str>::new();` to `HashMap::<&Vec<&str>, &str>::new();`, but then I get the same error, as well as this:

```rust
hashm.insert(&j, k);
             ^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
```

How can I rectify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```rust
let mut hashm = HashMap::<Vec<&str>, &str>::new();
```

The key and value types you have specified here are *borrowed.* This means that something else must *own* the keys and values. That can work in some cases, but in this case you're calling [`str::replace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.replace) which returns a *newly allocated `String`* which is then borrowed by `split`. That string cannot outlive the loop iteration — in fact, it's freed at the end of the `let j` statement. If you assigned the `String` to its own temporary variable, it'd last long enough that the call to `split` would compile, but it would still be freed at the end of the loop, so inserting it in `hashm` would fail.

If you make `String`s from the `&str`s for the keys then the code [will compile](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ca7574b0880d63bfcd6d802669b9b00b):

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

let mut hashm = HashMap::<Vec<String>, &str>::new();
for i in v {
    let s = i.split('\t').collect::<Vec<&str>>();
    let j = s[0]
        .replace(&['{', '}'][..], "")
        .split(", ")
        .map(str::to_owned)
        .collect();
    let k = s[1];
    hashm.insert(j, k);
}
```

Note that this HashMap still cannot live any longer than `v` because its values are still borrowed. If that is not what you want, then you must change its type to `HashMap<Vec<String>, String>` and use `hashm.insert(j, k.to_owned());`.

Comment: thank you.  I wanted the `HashMap` to live longer than `v`, so I needed to use `String` instead of `&str` (even when I defined `s`).  I guess I have one more clarifying question: what is `j` being "borrowed" _from_?

Comment: @JakeIreland In your original code, `.replace(...)` constructed a new `String` and `.split(", ")` borrowed from it. The same sort of problem would have occurred if you tried to put the string in the HashMap without splitting it; it's the lifetime of what a reference refers to (what it borrows) that matters, not how you got that reference.